# Removeing a thin white border on the home page with VUE Application

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, html

Hello Vue/css Experts,

I am pretty new for VUE, and i am trying to learn now,
With all the VUE application's that i develop, there seems to be an thin white border at the top and left side of the page, It become annoying when i have a dark background. is there any way to eliminate it??

below is the code

```
<!-- main.js-->  
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
})


<!-- App.vue-->
<template>
  <div id="app" class="initial">
      <router-view class='initial'></router-view>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";
import Cookies from "js-cookie";
export default {
  name: "app",
  mounted() {}
};
</script>
<style>
.initial {
  background-size: cover;
  background: linear-gradient(
    to bottom,
    rgb(98, 208, 223) 0%,
    rgb(7, 65, 73) 100%
  );
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
</style>
```

Below is the image of the browser page, where a thin white gap.

Basically the background is not covering the entire browser page

[image: background]

and Even the scroll bar appears by default, what should i need to change here, just to fill entire background with out scroll bar

Thanks

Comment: this is the default body margin as set by your browsers user-agent-stylesheet. add 'body{margin:0;}' to your styles

Comment: Thanks schellmax for that, making top: 0 and left: 0 worked for me. somehow margin:0 didn't bring me the results.

Answer (score 9):

It's the default margin.
You can fix it by placing the below-given css at the beginning of your stylesheet.

```
 * {
       margin: 0;
   }
```

P.S.  * - Selects all elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this issue by creating a global CSS file and add the following code.

```
*{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a body style under the App.vue file would be enough:

```
<style>
  body {
    margin: 0;
  }
</style>
```

ps: Enhanced the comment of @schellmax.